# MN relationships in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, orm

ZF has a very nice feature which is called **findManyToManyRowset** which returns you directly a collection of objects from a MN connection. The whole purpose of MN is to get the information from the other table, not from the connection table.

We have this schema:

```
- users
  - id
  - name

- groups
  - id
  - name

- user_has_groups
  - user_id
  - group_id
```

I want to create a user function that will return directly a collection of group objects and not a collection of user_has_groups objects.

```
$user->UserHasGroups ;// returns a collection of user_has_groups
$user->Groups; // returns Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
```

Is there a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine handles this automatically assuming your schema is set up correctly.  I only use Doctrine as part of Symfony, so my `schema.yml` would look something like this.  You may need to alter it if your Doctrine install uses a different method to define your schema:

```
Users:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string
  relations:
    Groups:
      refClass: UserHasGroups
      local: user_id
      foreign: group_id

Groups:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string
  relations:
    Users:
      refClass: UserHasGroups
      local: group_id
      foreign: id

UserHasGroups
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    group_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
```

Doctrine will use the `UserHasGroups` class as a many-to-many join table.  Then, calling `$user->Groups` will get you all associated `Groups` objects.

As a side note, I would change your model names to the singular form, eg `User`, `Group`.  `$user = new Users()` implies at first glance that you're creating multiple users in one go, which I presume you're not :-)

See the [Doctrine join table docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships:join-table-associations) for further details.

Comment: Thanks. I think I my autogenerated Yaml from existing tables is not creating a refClass attribute, but only relations with the intermediary table like ( UserHasGroups: local: id  foreign: user_id      type: many). Now at least I know what to look for. Thanks